# Filtering vertices with properties GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, filter, spark-graphx

Hi I am trying to filter these triplets by their properties and print them but I am having trouble. An example of some triplets in the graph are:

```
SongProperty(Song,Dernière danse) --- GenericMusicProperties(Sung) ---> ArtistProperty(Artist,indila,-1)
SongProperty(Song,Watagatapitusberry) --- GenericMusicProperties(Sung) ---> ArtistProperty(Artist,pitbull,$45 Million)
SongProperty(Song,This Is How It Feels) --- GenericMusicProperties(WrittenBy) ---> WriterProperty(Writer,Clint Boon)
```

I am trying to extract the Songs whose name is Watagatapitusberry.

I am trying with this filter:

```
 val qry = allGraph.vertices.filter{
  case (vp: SongProperty) => vp.songName == "Watagatapitusberry"
}
```

but I am not sure if it is correct and how to print the result.

These are the classes used as vertices and edges

```
class EdgeProperty extends Serializable
case class GenericMusicProperties(edgeType: String) extends EdgeProperty

case class WriterWriterProperties(weight: String, edgeType: String) extends EdgeProperty

case class ArtistWriterProperties(weight: String, edgeType: String) extends EdgeProperty

case class ArtistGenreProperties(weight: String, edgeType: String) extends EdgeProperty


class VertexProperty() extends Serializable

case class SongProperty(val vertexType: String, val songName: String) extends VertexProperty

case class BillboardProperty(val vertexType: String, val rank: Int, val year: Int) extends VertexProperty

case class ArtistProperty(val vertexType: String, val artistName: String, val netWorth: String) extends VertexProperty

case class WriterProperty(val vertexType: String, val writerName: String) extends VertexProperty

case class GenreProperty(val vertexType: String, val genreName: String) extends VertexProperty

case class GrammyProperty(val vertexType: String, val grammyNo: Int) extends VertexProperty

case class AliasProperty(val vertexType: String, val alias: String) extends VertexProperty
```

Comment: To print it, try this: 
qry.foreach(println)

Comment: Thanks it worked...is it possible to fix the filter to get the whole triplet?

Comment: It depends on what you expect to get. Does allGraph.vertices contain only SongProperty?

Comment: No, some contain SongProperty - ArtistProperty, others SongProperty - WriterProperty, ArtistProperty - WriterProperty etc...

Comment: Is ArtistProperty a case class? What does it contain? What about GenericMusicProperties, does allGraph.vertices contain this?

Comment: ArtistProperty is a case class. I included all case classes that I have in my graph for both vertices and edges. Even edges are different from one triplet to another

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter by only SongProperty, by songName and rest of elements of VertexProperty type leave in collection you should do like this:

```
list.filter {
  case s: SongProperty => s.songName == "Watagatapitusberry"
  case _ => true
}
```

As an example, for input:

```
val list = List(SongProperty("type1", "Strangers In the night"), 
               SongProperty("type1", "Watagatapitusberry"), 
               AliasProperty("type2", "alias1"), 
               GenreProperty("type1", "unknown"))
```

result will be:

```
List(SongProperty(type1,Watagatapitusberry), 
     AliasProperty(type2,alias1), 
     GenreProperty(type1,unknown))
```

Comment: Can you apply list.filter on a graph?